# Simple code in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi i wrote a simple code in Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Lakshmen");
    return 0;
}
```

I ended up having these errors:

```
'Lakshmen.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Lakshmen\Release\Lakshmen.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Lakshmen.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Lakshmen.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Lakshmen.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Lakshmen.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[13376] Lakshmen.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the symbols from Microsoft.
Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and check Microsoft Symbol Server and in the Cache symbols in the directory text box below, enter a path to a directory where you want to cache these symbols.